# How to do something after my recyclerview has changed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and and a textview in my activity
I want to show my list size in textview but I need to change it whenever my list size has changed
question is how can I make my activity listen to recyclerview after recyclerview has changed

this can clear  my question: [image: my question]

Comment: can you write your code?

Comment: You can use AdapterDataObserver( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver.html), but it is not the best way in this case. I think that you should change the way you handling item changing, but i can't say more without your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Whenever your recyclerView is notified for dataChange, write**

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(yourAdapter.getItemCount()));
```

**If on buttonClick, you are adding data into list, you will have to notify the adapter that data has been changed**

let's take an example as below,

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                list.add(question);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               textView.setText(String.valueOf(yourAdapter.getItemCount()));
            }
        });
```

**If you are removing data from list then you will have position from where you are removing the data**

I think that operation is being done in adapter, so to get that data into relevant activity or fragment you can use interface.

Check for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574358/passing-values-from-recycler-adapter-to-fragment-in-android/49574669#49574669) at some similar type of question

Comment: may I know how can I recognize when does my recyclerview notified?

Comment: How you are adding your data to list? can you please put the full code?

Comment: got it ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Wc! Happy coding